# How to programmatically set node field values.

Tags: entities

I have a content type.  I have firstname, lastname and email address fields.  I need the default value for each field to be the firstname, lastname and email address of the user profile.  Also, I need to prevent the user from modifying these values. The user should be able to see the values by default, but the user shouldn't be able to edit them.

Comment: Drupal 6 or 7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
global $user;
    if($form_id == 'story_node_form' ){
    if ($user->uid) {
profile_load_profile($user);
        $form['field_first_name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'First name',
           '#default_value' => $user->profile_first_name,
            '#disabled'=> 'TRUE'            
        );
        $form['#submit'][] = 'test_field_first_name_submit';
    }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom module and add use hook_form_alter to change the default_value of your field and change them to `#disabled => true`. Here is an example. Don't forget to chage modulename to the name of your module and form-id to the id of your form :-).

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    if ($form['#id'] == 'form-id') {
        $form['field_name'] = array(
            '#disabled' => TRUE,
            '#default_value' => $user->name
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How can I get the "id" of the content type?

Comment: You can use dsm($form); (if the devel module is enabled) to check the id.

Comment: The form ID is already passed as argument to the hook implementation; there is no need to use `$form['#id']`.

Comment: I forgot to say that my version of drupal is 6, this code works for drupal 6?

I don't know to replacement this:  if ($form['#id'] == 'form-id') 

if the field of profile is profile_first_name, in default_value should be $user->profile_user_name?

Thanks.

Comment: This code works for Drupal 6.

To know the replacement of form-id you have to run dsm($form['#id']); check the result and replace.

if the field of profile is profile_first_name, in default_value should be $user->profile_user_name?

if you want the name of the loggedin user use $user->name

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am beginner with modules.  I have activated the module devel and I put the dsm and I can't see the form[#id].  However, I'll review later and I'll give an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: The code doesn't work.  I tested your code and the field is not disabled and the value =0.  Here I put the code:
function primermodulo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    global $user;
    if ($form['#id'] == 'story-node-form') {
        $form['field_first_name'] = array(
           '#disabled' => TRUE,
            '#default_value' =>$user->name
        );
    }
}

Thanks.

Comment: What it the result of dsm($form['field_first_name']) ?

Comment: 0 (Array, 10 elements)
      #type (String, 14 characters ) text_textfield
      #default_value (Array, 1 element)
            field_first_name (String, 5 characters ) black
      #title (String, 10 characters ) First Name
      #description (String, 0 characters )
      #required (Boolean) FALSE
      #weight (Integer) 0
      #delta (Integer) 0
      #columns (Array, 1 element)
            0 (String, 5 characters ) value
      #field_name (String, 16 characters ) field_first_name
      #type_name (String, 5 characters ) story

Comment: I tested this code :
function primermodulo_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    if($form_id == 'story_node_form'){
        $form['field_first_name'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => 'Name profile',
            '#default_value' => $user->name,
   '#disabled'=> 'TRUE'
        );
        $form['#submit'][] = 'primermodulo_field_first_name_submit';
    }
}

the field is disabled but the default value doesn't show in the field.  $user->name doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.